# Disable allow-discards on encrypted partition

Tags: partition, encryption, disk-encryption, trim, fstrim

I have the following partition table:

```
NAME            
nvme0n1         
├─nvme0n1p1           part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p2           part
  └─crypt             crypt
    ├─crypt-swap      lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─crypt-root      lvm   /
    └─crypt-home      lvm   /home
```

As the drive is an SSD, I would like to perform [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) command in order to increase performance/lifetime of the disk itself.

In particular, I would like to enable periodic TRIM.

Because the second partition (i.e., `nvme0n1p2`) is encrypted, TRIM will be inhibited because of security implications (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard/TRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_(SSD)).

However, it is possible to enable TRIM on encrypted partition by configuring `encrypt` on the opening.

As I my partition is opened at kernel boot, I've modified kernel parameters (i.e., `allow-discards`):

```
cryptdevice=/dev/sdaX:root:allow-discards
```

(*Note that the partition naming and volume name are not relevant in the above snippet.*).

By doing that, I was indeed successfully able to run TRIM command on the disk:

```
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/nvme0n1p2 | grep Flags
Flags:   allow-discards
```

And:

```
# fstrim ...
/home: [..] trimmed on ...
/: [..] trimmed on
```

So far, so good.

---

The problem arose when I tried to restore to the original state.

I have removed the kernel parameter `allow-discards`, but `Flags` on partition still shows `allow-discards` and `fstrim` command successfully complete its job.

- How is that possible?
- How to restore denying of discards on the encrypted partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out, LUK2 can permanently store metadata in the header.

It is possible to enable `allow-discards` and store in the partition itself (without any further configuration -e.g., kernel parameters) with the command:

```
cryptsetup --allow-discards --persistent refresh root
```

Evidently, I issued this command in the past enabling the discarding option.

It is possible to remove the flag with:

```
cryptsetup --persistent refresh root
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html

> Refreshing the device without any optional parameter will refresh
> the device with default setting (respective to device type).

Comment: I guess you have to omit the `--allow-discards` argument in the second command in order to remove, don't you?